# SQLite Commands to Store Date and Float values

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

For Storing Values in SQLite.I wrote the below code in -(void)initWithPrimaryKey method.

```
self.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(init_statement, 0)];
```

this is for string. what should i write if i wanna save date and a float value??
should i write the same thing??

As i Copied this code from a tutorial can someone tell me what that '0' at the last stand for?

Comment: you are retrieving or storing....??

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wish to work with raw sqlite, the open-source [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) is a commonly-used Cocoa wrapper for sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

```
        use this one
       if insert
        sqlite3_bind_double(init_statement, 1, date);

    if retrieve date then

double Date= sqlite3_column_double(init_statement, 1);
```

Comment: it represent your column number from where u insert or retrive date